# Angular Dart Menu Bar

Tags: angular-dart

I'd like to implement a menu bar similar to the one used in Google Docs. (ie: File, Edit, View with drop downs, multi levels, keyboard navigations, short cuts, etc..) I noticed that "Menu Bar" is implemented in AngularJS (here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menuBar) Is there something like this available in Angular Dart? If not, what is the best way to pull this code over?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We don't provide a widget like that. It isn't in our design language for most of our apps, and I don't see us adding one.

I'd look around and see if the OS community has one somewhere.